# Configure Azure Traffic Manager for Load Balancing with Weighted method on same region 2 App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing, azure-traffic-manager

Trying to configure Traffic Manager for load balancing with Weighted method, both endpoints are at West US region using standard 2 plan.

Azure App Services:
A(West US) - 50% Traffic
B(West US) - 50% Traffic

First endpoint added successfully with 50 weight, When I am adding the second App Service as endpoint of traffic manager I'm getting this error:

> Failed to save configuration changes to Traffic Manager profile
>   '*****'. Error: Some of the provided Azure Website endpoints are not
>   valid: One or more conflicts detected in traffic manager
>   configuration. Multiple domains point to region 'West US':
>   a.azurewebsites.net, b.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 3):

Typically, Traffic Manager is used to direct traffic to applications deployed in different regions. However, it can also be used where an application has more than one deployment in the same region. **The Traffic Manager Azure endpoints do not permit more than one Web App endpoint from the same Azure region to be added to the same Traffic Manager profile**.

So it is not possible with Web Apps

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#traffic-manager-endpoints

Comment: I want to achieve quoted "However, it can also be used where an application has more than one deployment in the same region"

Comment: i have two apps, deployed same code in both instance. both are on west us region. for the load balancing purpose i want to create traffic manager with sharing 50% load on both instances.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can read, that is not possible with Azure Web Apps @Lalit